# clearfix not working for position absolute

Tags: html, css

I have a div containing position absolute and float left and right. Now i want to place an image below the first div.

Now the problem is the image overlapping below the first div. I want the image to display below first div without overlapping.

https://jsfiddle.net/jv7afgn1/

```
<div class="top">
    <div class="left" align="center">
        <p><a href="#">Sell</a></p>
        <p><a href="#">Download App</a></p>
        <p><a href="#">24x7 Customer Care</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="right" align="center">
        <p><a href="#">Track Order</a></p>
        <p><a href="#">Help</a></p>
        <p><a href="#">About</a></p>
        <p><a href="#">Contact</a></p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>

<div class="logo_menu">
    <p><img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="" title="" /></p>
</div>

.clearfix {
    clear:both;
}
/* Top */
.top {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    background:#E9E9E9;
    position:absolute;
    padding:10px;
}
.top .left {
    float:left;
}
.top .left p {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 10px 0 10px;
    font-size:12px;
}
.top .left p a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#B5B5B5;
}
.top .left p a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
    color:#FD6123;
}
.top .right {
    float:right;
}
.top .right p {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 10px 0 10px;
    font-size:12px;
}
.top .right p a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#B5B5B5;
}
.top .right p a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
    color:#FD6123;
}

/* Menu and Logo */
.logo_menu {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

Comment: Absolute positioning takes an element out of normal flow, and a clearfix can not help with that.

Comment: "Just have a look for my code in jsfiddle." No, I'm not gonna. You have been here long enough to know your code needs to be in the question. Do not circumvent the quality filter.

Comment: do you need like this? https://jsfiddle.net/jv7afgn1/1/

Comment: @CBroe : Then how to fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you even have to absolute position the logo?

> An absolute positioned element is on "it's own layer" of the homepage,
>   so trying to clear floats wont work.

My clearfix usually looks like this:

```
.clearfix:after {
  clear:both;
  display:block;
  content: "";
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jv7afgn1/4/

Answer (score 0):

Add padding top value equal to height of your navigation bar fixed at the top
**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jv7afgn1/1/)**

```
.logo_menu {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
padding-top:30px;
}
```